# Spotify urls regex

Tags: javascript, regex, spotify

I am having some trouble with Regex. Basically what I want to do is take any either of these types of spotify urls for a playlist

`https://open.spotify.com/user/spotify/playlist/37i9dQZF1DZ06evO2ZpGiQ?si=-6S0EBlURrao__YyIOW6bg`

or

`spotify:user:spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DZ06evO2ZpGiQ`

And get the user id which would be `spotify` for these URLs and would like to get the playlist id which would be `37i9dQZF1DZ06evO2ZpGiQ` for these URLs

I also would like to have some regex that would make sure it is either one of these URL types.

So far I have tried this regex to check if it is a spotify url using this regex:

`^(spotify:|https:\/\/[a-z]+\.spotify\.com\/)` but it only matches the top URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I get the immutable parts of each candidate strings which are `https://open.spotify.com/user/spotify/playlist` and `spotify:user:spotify:playlist` in a first group then I capture the playlist id in a second group and the rest can be ignored.

You can see it at work there: https://regex101.com/r/tDtsTS/1

`^(https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/user\/spotify\/playlist\/|spotify:user:spotify:playlist:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*)$`

Comment: This works great, it does give me the playlist id, however it does not retrieve the user id as well. How would I go about adding that?

Comment: I updated it to this `^(https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/user\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/playlist\/|spotify:user:([a-zA-Z0-9]+):playlist:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*)$` based upon your answer and it seems to grab all information I needed, is there anything about this you would change?

Comment: Oh I didn't realise that the second Spotify was the user id, nope looks all good.

Comment: Not complete, a Spotify username can contain dots and dashes, like spotify:user:ege.basaran:playlist:0HVvyU1bvNsyBWEpbc7N2M

Answer (score 1):

For your given examples you could also match the user id and the playlist id using an  alternation `|` for only the first part where you do not yet want to capture values and capture the separator in a capturing group `([\/:])`. Then you could use a backreference `\1`

Then you can refer to the same group number for the username and the playlist. The username will be in group 2 and the playlist in group 3.

`^(?:https:\/\/open\.spotify\.com|spotify)([\/:])user\1([^\/]+)\1playlist\1([a-z0-9]+)`

**Details**

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `https:\/\/open\.spotify\.com` Match literally (escape the dot `\.` to match it literally)
  - `|` Or
  - `spotify` match literally
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `([\/:])` Capture `/` or `:` in a group using a character class so it can be used with a backreference to this group (**group 1**)
- `user\1` Match `user` followed by the backreference `\1`
- `([^\/]+)` Capture the user id (**group 2**) using a negated character class to match not a forward slash
- `\1playlist\1` match playlist using 2 backreferences (like `:playlist:` or `/playlist/`)
- `([a-z0-9]+)` Capturing the playlist id (**group 3**)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vyNpBX/1/)

You could use the case insensitive flag `/i` to match upper and lowercase characters.

```js
const strings = [
  'https://open.spotify.com/user/spotify/playlist/37i9dQZF1DZ06evO2ZpGiQ?si=-6S0EBlURrao__YyIOW6bg',
  'spotify:user:spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DZ06evO2ZpGiQ'
];
let regex = /^(?:https:\/\/open\.spotify\.com|spotify)([\/:])user\1([^\/]+)\1playlist\1([a-z0-9]+)/gi;
strings.forEach((str) => {
  while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log("user id: " + m[2]);
    console.log("playlist id: " + m[3]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy, just use character classes.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/eQFWuR/1

Regex `spotify[\/:]playlist[\/:](.+)[\s?]`

Comment: @IamNguele I think that's okay though

Comment: Also it doesn't capture the playlist id.

Comment: @IamNguele yes it does

Comment: Now it does hahaha

Comment: @IamNguele hehe